# Map all 404 urls in / to a specif servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I need to map all urls in the / which otherwise would give 404 so they get served by a specific servlet. How do I do that?

so /unknownUrl1 and /unknownUrl2 should be shown using my UnhandledUrlsServlet while /unknown/somethingElse should just give the normal 404 error page.

In case this is not possible, something which also catch  /unknown/somethingElse would be my fallback. (Then my servlet will just have to look at the url, to decide what to

Using Apache tomcat 8.5

Updated:
The use case is that users on our website need to be able to select a username, and then their personal page should be accessable at example.com/coolusername

I tried to use

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CatchAll</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But that catches all urls even in folders. So it also catches example.com/folder/staticImage.jpg making servering any static resources impossible.

Using the  solution would work perfectly, if only I could got the real url the user typed. I can then use that to lookup the name to see if it's a username, and then change the response code to 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also put a `filter-mapping` on `/*`
Those that match your current user database are handled by the filter.
Those that aren't users just pass through via `chain.doFilter()` and resolve in the way they otherwise would, for example, an HTML page or different servlet.
That would invert the priority somewhat in which a user might take precedence over an existing page.
The best solution perhaps is to have a `servlet-mapping` on `/users/*` and so you're not poluting your base url space with user content.

Comment: I used a filter mapping, which is working perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>UserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: But how do I then get the real url the user requested in my ErrorHandler? request.getRequestURI() and request.getServletPath() just give me the /ErrorHandler url while getPathInfo() returns null

Comment: See update. (Using Referer does not work. There might not be a referrer).

Comment: Looking at your update, I feel very strongly that this isn't an appropriate use of the 404 mechanism.  You should use a /* servlet-mapping.